# How can i capture exceptions values using powershell

Tags: sql, powershell

Hi i'm new to this and want to capture exception and store values in SQL database but its not capturing.

My current flow is something like this:
[image]

My code:

```
try
{
    try
    {
    $path='D:\'+$name # location not present in my system to throw exception
    "$(get-date -format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"):Folder Name : $($name)" | out-file $LogFile -Append
    if (Test-Path -Path $path)
    {
      $status='already exists'
      "$(get-date -format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"):Folder Already Exists" | out-file $LogFile -Append
      write-output $status
      $msg='Already Existed'
    }
    #else
    #{
      #Creating a folder
      #New-Item -Path $path -ItemType Directory
      #"$(get-date -format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"):Folder Created" | out-file $LogFile -Append
      #$status='Success'
      #$msg='Successfully Created'
     #}
     }
     catch
     {
     #to catch above exceptions
     $status='Failed'
     Write-Host "`nError Message: " $_.Exception.Message
     Write-Host "`nError in Line: " $_.InvocationInfo.Line
     Write-Host "`nError in Line Number: "$_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
     Write-Host "`nError Item Name: "$_.Exception.ItemName
     "$(get-date -format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"):$($_.Exception.Message)" | out-file $LogFile -Append 
     $msg=$_.Exception.Message
     }
             
    $CheckQuery="SELECT COUNT(1) AS TABLECOUNT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = '$($name)'"
    $InsertQuery="INSERT INTO [$($Database)].[dbo].[$($name)]
                           ([DATE],[HOST_NAME],[STATUS],[MESSAGE])
                     VALUES('$date','$ComputerName','$status','$msg')
                "
    $CreateQuery='CREATE TABLE '+$($name)+' (DATE NVARCHAR(MAX),HOST_NAME NVARCHAR(MAX),STATUS NVARCHAR(MAX),MESSAGE NVARCHAR(MAX))'
    #other sql part making connection and calling queries
}
catch
{
#catching SQL part exceptions
Write-Host "`nError Message: " $_.Exception.Message
Write-Host "`nError in Line: " $_.InvocationInfo.Line
Write-Host "`nError in Line Number: "$_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
Write-Host "`nError Item Name: "$_.Exception.ItemName
"$(get-date -format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"):$($_.Exception.Message)" | out-file $LogFile -Append 
}
```

Exception I'm getting in powershell is [image]

But in SQL it stores blank data as shown in below image[image]

As I'm new to this ,any help will be thankfull.

Comment: Hi @zett42, any suggestions on how can i save exceptions in database

Comment: Exception message contains single quotes `'`, which conflicts with single quotes in SQL query. Escape the message for SQL or use parameterized query.